# identification condition in factor model

Tags: multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, identifiability

Consider the following factor structure:

$\Sigma=\Lambda \Lambda' + \Phi$

where $\Sigma$ is $p \times p$, $\Lambda$ is $p \times m$ without any restrictions and $\Phi$ is a $p \times p$ diagonal matrix with distinct elements. Suppose that a sample covariance matrix $S$ is available as an estimator for $\Sigma$.

To identify $\Lambda$ and $\Phi$, an order condition $p(p+1)/2 \ge pm+p$ needs to be satisfied. For example, if $p=6$ and $m=2$, this condition is satisfied. However, if $p=6$ and $m=3$, this conditions is not satisfied. What should I do for identification in such a case?

Comment: Are you sure of the "condition" formula? - where `p` multiplier appears to cancel out. Where have you taken the formula from and what's its meaning?

Comment: $p(p+1)/2$ is the number of distinct elements of $\Sigma$ and $pm+p$ is the number of unknown parameters. So I thought that the number of parameters need to be equal to or smaller than $p(p+1)/2$.

Comment: The `p` diagonal "parameters" $\Phi$, uniquenesses, are not independent of the loadings $\Lambda$: if you know all the loadings you automatically know the vector of uniquenesses. So, `+p` on the right-hand side of the inequality is excess, in any case. But actually, and counter your formula, the formal most general restriction of the common factor model is just that `p>m`. (More stringent restriction might appear in specific settings or under additional theoretical considerations.)

Comment: What I want to know is written in Anderson and Rubin (1956)- a classical paper on factor model. On page 117, the last two paragraphs: "if $C$ is negative, we can expect that $-C$ additional restrictions are necessary for identification". I don't know how to impose those restrictions in practice. Is there any rule? http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/math/ucb/text/math_s3_v5_article-08.pdf

Comment: Leave a link for the article?